# Counting Occurrences of Object Values

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to loop through some data in a JSON file and count the number of same cities/occurrences...

```
var json = [
  { "city": "California" },
  { "city": "California" },
  { "city": "California" },
  { "city": "Texas" },
  { "city": "Florida" }
];

var obj = {};

for (var i = 0, j = json.length; i < j; i++) {
  if (obj[json[i]]) {
    obj[json[i]]++;
  }
  else {
    obj[json[i]] = 1;
  } 
}

console.log(obj);
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/f2939ucw/

The problem is that the object returned is only returning back the number of objects within the array and not the same occurrences of cities.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An alternate way of phrasing this:

```
json.reduce(function(sums,entry){
   sums[entry.city] = (sums[entry.city] || 0) + 1;
   return sums;
},{});
```

[`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) calls a callback on each element of the array, passing the return of the previous call in as the first parameter in the next. (The `{}` at the end is the initial value, passed into the first call)

So this is doing exactly what you did - creating an empty object, iterating through the array, and accumulating totals inside the object. It's just doing it tersely.

Comment: Nice approach, very elegant! Thanks for taking your time to post this. I decided to use this method instead.

Comment: How would you do the same thing but instead of one object {key: count, key2: count} I would like to return an array [{key:count}, {key2:count}]. Is that possible?

Comment: The easiest way to do that would be to use the code in the answer as the first step (collecting the sums) and then convert to the form you want as a second step.

Answer (score 4):

Nevermind, long day.

I noticed I forgot to access the property **city**

**The Fix:**
obj[json[i].city]

Thanks!