# javascript count number values repeated in a jsonArray items

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i need to count the number of occurrences of values in jsonArray items in javascript.
consider this as my `jsonArray`:

```
{"name":"jack","age":23},
{"name":"john","age":20},
{"name":"alison","age":23},
{"name":"steve","age":25},
.
.
.
```

now for example i need to know how many times each age is repeated in this array, i want to count each value for each property, i mean i need a result like this :

```
 name : {"jack" : 2,"james" : 10,"john" : 1,....}

 age : {"23":10,"20":15,"25":2,....}
```

what is the simplest way to achieve this?

EDIT :
  my array is very big and i don't want to call count function for each value. i want a code to count each value repeat times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting Occurrences of Object Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957390/counting-occurrences-of-object-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can have a look at [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
function mapToProp(data, prop) {
  return data
    .reduce((res, item) => Object
      .assign(res, {
        [item[prop]]: 1 + (res[item[prop]] || 0)
      }), Object.create(null))
  ;
}


const data = [
  {"name": "jack", "age": 23},
  {"name": "john", "age": 20},
  {"name": "alison", "age": 23},
  {"name": "steve", "age": 25}
];

console.log('mapAndCountByAge', mapToProp(data, 'age'))
```

Comment: "I want to count each value for each property"

Comment: this is very good, but what about a big array without knowing the values?
is this possible to count each value without knowing it? just count the occurrence of each value in a property

Comment: @m7majidi Yes, and that exact question is why I flagged this as a duplicate. Check out the question I linked in the comment. This question has been asked numerous times and is a matter of a simple google search.

Comment: edited. @mhodges I was not aware about duplicates, downvoting is still not needed because this isn't a duplicate until it is a duplicate.

Comment: @Hitmands I downvoted because it doesn't answer the OP's question of "I want to count each value for each property", but I think downvoting because of an obvious duplicate would not be inappropriate. You've been around long enough to know that this question has been asked before.

Comment: 1. it actually suits the OP. 2. as I said, it is a duplicate when it will be marked as duplicate, until that anybody is free and welcome to answer and you should not downvote because someone does what SO is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object, where the keys and the values are used as property for the count.

```js
var array = [{ name: "jack", age:23 }, { 'name': "john", age: 20 }, { name: "alison", age: 23 }, { name: "steve", age: 25 }],
    result = {};

array.forEach(function (o) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        result[k] = result[k] || {};
        result[k][o[k]] = (result[k][o[k]] || 0) + 1;
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant as [Nina's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44829459/javascript-count-number-values-repeated-in-a-jsonarray-items#answer-44830203) and [Hitmands'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44829459/javascript-count-number-values-repeated-in-a-jsonarray-items#answer-44829654) answers, but this is easier to understand for beginners (in case any beginner is reading this).

```js
var jsonArray = [
  {"name": "John", "age": 20},
  {"name": "John", "age": 21},
  {"name": "Doe", "age": 21},
  {"name": "Doe", "age": 23},
  {"name": "Doe", "age": 20},
];
var names = [],
    ages = [];

// separate name data and age data into respective array
// only need to access the original data once
jsonArray.forEach(function(val){
    names.push(val['name']);
    ages.push(val['age']);
});

function aggregate(array){
    var obj = {};

    array.forEach(function(val){
        if (!obj[val])
            // create new property if property is not found
            obj[val] = 1;
        else
            // increment matched property by 1
            obj[val]++;
    });
    
    return JSON.stringify(obj);
}

console.log("Names: " + aggregate(names));
console.log("Ages: " + aggregate(ages));
```

[In my opinion](http://jsben.ch/S8xH4), Nina has the best answer here.

**EDIT**

In fact, when presented with large dataset (as OP stated that "the array is very big"), this method is about 45% faster than Nina's answer and about 81% faster than Hitmand's answer according to [jsben.ch](http://jsben.ch/YRubI). I don't know why though.