# javascript count daily occurrencies from a datatable for the creation of a linechart

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, chart.js

I have a datatable with a Datetime column and each day the table gets populated with new data with the relative timestamp in the datetime column. I need to calculate, for each day, how many occurrences I have because I need to have an array for the linechart I'm writing using chartjs. Here's the code for my chart:

```
function printChart() {
var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();
    var dateCol= $('tr>td:nth-child(7)');
    
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
          var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['total occurrencies'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Total distribution',
                data: [arrayOfOccurrencies],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
    
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
    
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
    
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }); 
    }
```

Here's the table I'm generating from a get response:

```
<table id="datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>software name</th>
      <th>windows version</th>
      <th>2020-09-01</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>


  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 1</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>2020-09-01</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 1</td>
      <td>winXp</td>
      <td>2020-09-02</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 2</td>
      <td>win7</td>
      <td>2020-09-03</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 3</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>2020-09-04</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 3</td>
      <td>winXp</td>
      <td>2020-09-04</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 4</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>2020-09-05</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 2</td>
      <td>winVista</td>
      <td>2020-09-06</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 4</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>2020-09-06</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 4</td>
      <td>win7</td>
      <td>2020-09-06</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 1</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>2020-09-07</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 4</td>
      <td>winXp</td>
      <td>2020-09-07</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's a possible output of my arrayOfOccurrencies:

```
2020-09-01, 2
2020-09-02, 1
2020-09-03, 1
2020-09-04, 2
2020-09-05, 1
2020-09-06, 3
2020-09-07, 2
```

How can I do that optimally in javascript/ajax/jquery?
I'm stuck because I don't know how to iterate through the date column in order to have a daily occurrencies count. How can I do that?
Thank you

EDIT: I have a database but I don't have access to it, I'm just receiving data as json and parsing it into a datatable

EDIT: I noticed that my datetime is in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS and I modified the code like this, but still is showing hours-minutes-seconds:

```
arrayOfOccurrencies = {};
$("tr>td:nth-child(4)").each(function(){
for (var i = 0; i < $("tr>td:nth-child(4)").length; i++) {
$("tr>td:nth-child(4)")[i] = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
i++;
};
  day = $(this).html();

  // If it's the first occurence we initialise it to 0
  if(typeof arrayOfOccurrencies[day] == "undefined"){
    arrayOfOccurrencies[day] = 0;
  }

  arrayOfOccurrencies[day] += 1;
})
```

and here's part of the newly created array:

```
2020-08-24 23:03:31: 1
2020-09-01 17:15:29: 1
2020-09-01 23:02:17: 1
2020-09-02 15:19:51: 1
```

it is still showing the hours-minutes-seconds. How can I modify my code in order to delete that section in the whole datatable?

Comment: (1) Do you actually have a database?  (2) Please add the desired result (matching your sample data) to your question (use [Edit])..

Comment: edited the question and answered your question: I have a database but I don't have access to it, I'm generating the datatable from the json I'm receiving

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to aggregate your data based on HTML content and not just from the original JSON?  If you already know how to get your JSON data, what other ***asynchronous*** operations do you anticipate?

Comment: I need to create a chart with chartjs and, in order to have a line chart, I need the daily amount of occurrencies.

Comment: Please **rewrite** your question and describe your **actual** task_. Also show the best attempt of your own code so far and explain where exactly you stuck.

Comment: I've rewritten the question with more explainations and the code I'm stuck on

Comment: Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44829459/javascript-count-number-values-repeated-in-a-jsonarray-items

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through your table and build an array object like  `{day1:value1, day2:value2, etc.}`

```js
    arrayOfOccurrencies = {};

// A class selector will be better but you don't have it in your example
    $("td:nth-child(4)").each(function(){
      day = $(this).html();

      // If it's the first occurence we initialise it to 0
      if(typeof arrayOfOccurrencies[day] == "undefined"){
        arrayOfOccurrencies[day] = 0;
      }
      
      arrayOfOccurrencies[day] += 1;
    })

    //console.log(arrayOfOccurrencies);

    // To display arrayOfOccurrencies you just need to loop and do what you want
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>software name</th>
      <th>windows version</th>
      <th>2020-09-01</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>


  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 1</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>2020-09-01</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 1</td>
      <td>winXp</td>
      <td>2020-09-02</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 2</td>
      <td>win7</td>
      <td>2020-09-03</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 3</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>2020-09-04</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 3</td>
      <td>winXp</td>
      <td>2020-09-04</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 4</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>2020-09-05</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 2</td>
      <td>winVista</td>
      <td>2020-09-06</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 4</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>2020-09-06</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 4</td>
      <td>win7</td>
      <td>2020-09-06</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 1</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>2020-09-07</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 4</td>
      <td>winXp</td>
      <td>2020-09-07</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

To loop and get elements I use JQuery but you can use whatever you want.

However I think it will be easier for you to count day occurencies when you build your table from json.

Comment: This is working, but it is not searching in the whole datatable, only in the visualized rows. I have a button number to switch between the datatable pages. Is there a way to implement this code to work in that case too?

Comment: So I think the hidden rows just doesn't exist in the DOM, Maybe `rows().data()` ( https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data() ) will work. I'll test later.

Comment: Also, I noticed that my datetime is in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS and I modified your code like in the edit, but still is showing hours-minutes-seconds. Is there a way to modify that section too?

Comment: I modified my answer according to what I did. Is there a way to fix like you suggested?